Git - Update feature branch without redoing previous conflict resolutions
In git I have a feature-branch which I just rebased of master. There were many conflicts and it took me a couple of days to get the feature-branch up and running with the latest changes from master.
Recently some changes have been made to a single file, Readme.md, in master and my feature-branch is again out of sync and requires an update.
Is it possible to update my feature-branch with the latest changes in Readme.md, without doing an entire rebase (don't want to go through the entire conflict resolution process again)?

A tool which can solve this sort of problem is git-rerere, but it needs to record the original conflict resolution so you'll have to do the conflict resolution one more time.

Yes, you just rebase as before. If only the readme changed, you will at most have to resolve conflicts in that file. BTW: If it honestly took you days to resolve the initial rebase, you either have a shitload of changes and many commits in between bases or you're doing something wrong. One thing to do wrong is to not have atomic commits, i.e. having back-and-forth changes on one file. Squash those first.

Also, if you rebased your changes before, you only have to rebase on top of the new commits on master now. If that only touched the readme.md, there should not be many conflicts this time around. Before you worry about potential conflicts, just give it a try and see what happens.

Yes. Initially I had to go through a lot of commits. Also after conflict resolution, I had to make even more changes on my side, to get the code building and running again.
I have now sqaushed all my commits into a single commit.
"Also, if you rebased your changes before, you only have to rebase on top of the new commits on master now. "
Yes, I did rebase my local branch. During a rebase when it replays my commit on master won't the conflicts show up again?

Just read the current README into your current working tree:
git fetch
git restore --source master -- path-to-README


And as a matter of general principle I cannot recommend rebasing your long-lived feature branch onto master, neither once nor repeatedly. If you want to keep developing your feature branch while updating it periodically from master, the way to update is to merge master into your feature branch. Don't worry, the PR will not contain the "changes" that are already in master.

I would add: Do merge master, but do not merge at any random time. Instead, pick versions of master that are of particular significance, like when it has reached a certain stability.

To rebase and keep feature branch changes whenever there is a conflict I used the merge strategy -Xtheirs
git checkout main                                                          
git pull cloud main
git checkout feature            
git rebase main -Xtheirs    

Successfully rebased and updated refs/heads/feature

I do wish you'd make up your mind what the branches are called; is the main branch main or master? — There is no need for the repeated checkouts in the first three lines. Just stay on feature and pull main by saying git fetch cloud main:main. Even better, delete the local main, since you are never going to use it for anything; then just rebase onto the remote-tracking main (or merge it, as I suggested in my answer).
